# Вызов деструктора для объекта в его методе

Tags: c++

Насколько безопасна такая вещь:

```
class A {
...
void remove() {
   this->~A;
}
...
```

Мы вызываем деструктор для объекта в его методе. Понятно, что если после этого мы вызовем объект (или его метод), то мы, в лучшем случае, получим ошибку (желаемое поведение), но насколько такой метод безопасен для уничтожения объектов? Поясню зачем это нужно: имеется некая программа, которая загружает динамические библиотеки и с помощью некой функции создает объекты, реализованные в ней. При этом объекты могут быть размещены как на стэке (если это синглтон), так и в куче (когда применяется динамическое выделение памяти). При этом из самой программы нельзя сказать, как была выделена память под тот или иной объект, а значит либо объект должен позаботится о своем удалении самостоятельно, либо изменить интерфейсы так, чтобы они могли сообщать как была выделена память под объект. При этом для всех загруженных объектов справедливо то, что они больше не используются после вызова функции `remove`. Так можно ли так поступать? Не возникнут ли проблемы при выходе из метода после вызова деструктора?

Comment: Проблемы от вызова деструктора сами по себе не возникнут, но вы можете гарантировать, что никто больше не попытается получить доступ к объекту после окончания работы деструктора?

Comment: А если он в куче - то вы планируете утечку памяти? Ведь простой вызов деструктора *память под объект* не освободит. Ну и - надо гарантировать, что повторный вызов деструктора (а он, скорее всего, будет вызван, даже если вы не будете пользоваться объектом - например, при выходе из области видимости для стекового объекта) не приведет к неприятностям.

Comment: @Harry вопрос не про освобождение памяти, а про поведение после вызова деструктора, но чтобы вам было спокойнее, замечу, что `this->~A()` в случае с кучей - просто заменяется на `delete this;`. При этом при вызове `delete` вызывается деструктор. Так что еще раз повторюсь: вопрос не про освобождение памяти, а про вызов деструктора из метода объекта.

Comment: @Harry стоп, а как это повторный вызов для деструктора стэкового объекта - не приведет к неприятностям? Ну а если у нас в деструкторе освобождается память динамически выделенной сишной строки (которая является членом класса)? Это разве не приведет к неприятностям?

Comment: Ситуация, когда *"нельзя сказать, как была выделена память под тот или иной объект"* говорит о том, что вас происходит утечка памяти, так как нет владения объектами. Соответственно надо разделить объекты, которыми владеет вызывающий код (то бишь из динамической памяти) и объекты, которыми он не владеет (выделенные на стеке, в глобальной области, как подъобъекты других объектов и т.п.). Если объекты создаются в некой функции, то по-хорошему они должны уничтожаться вызовом симметричной функции, а заботы о том, как там правильно разрушить объект и освободить память ложатся на эту функцию.

Comment: @VTT нет, это не говорит, о том, что есть утечка памяти - как вы пришли к такому выводу? Память освобождается (о чем говорит и `valgrind` и `sanitizer`), я лишь не знаю насколько безопасен вызов деструктора из метода объекта.

Comment: Приведет. А я о чем пишу? Перечитайте: "надо гарантировать, что повторный вызов деструктора ... не приведет к неприятностям". Вы выбросили мое "надо гарантировать", как тот журналист, который после того, как ему ученый на интервью сказал "выдернутые из контекста, мои слова бессмысленны", напечатал - "ученый признался, что его слова бессмысленны"... :) Что касается вызова деструктора из метода - не скажу, что там стандарт говорит, но при указанных условиях - не вижу препятствий; в свое время Borland в TurboVision именно так и поступал.

Comment: @Harry ах, да, не заметил скобку.

Comment: Ну как же: сценарий 1 - объект размещен на куче - вызов деструктора не освободит память; сценарий 2 - объект размещен на стеке - вызов деструктора тоже не освободит память, а при повторном вызове деструктора при выходе объекта из области видимости будет неопределенное поведение.

Comment: Необходимость вызова деструктора в функции-члене класса хорошо описана в книге Дональд Бокс - "Сущность техологи COM".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы освобождаете память кучи с помощью `delete`, там будет автоматически вызван деструктор. Один раз. Не вижу проблем. Другое дело, если вы не освобождаете память. Или освобождаете потом. Тогда у деструкторов нужен будет знак : надо или нет .

Двойной вызов деструктора приведёт к неадекватному поведению проги. Есть рецепт слежения о состоянии объекта :

```
class A {
public:
A(){}
~A(){if(valid){ ... valid=false;}}
private :
volatile bool valid { true } ;
} ;
```

Это приведёт к возможности адекватного двойного вызова деструктора.

Comment: нет ничего отрицательного в двойном вызове деструктора, если сам деструктор  не уничтожает свои члены.  Деструктор  сам по себе не освобождает память, а вызывается перед освобождением памяти. А память освобождает распределитель памяти.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вызов деструктора для унитоженного объекта - undefined behavior.

Comment: @Croessmah, для уничтоженного обьекта да, но я  говорил не о вызове деструктора после уничтожения обьекта, а о вызове деструктора существующего обьекта...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan после первого вызова деструктора время жизни объекта заканчивается и повторный вызов приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan 12.4/15 - Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists; the behavior is undefined if the destructor is invoked for an object whose lifetime has ended (3.8).  
То есть после первого вызова деструктора объект является уничтоженным, а второй вызов деструктора приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Answer (score 1):

Безопасность зависит от того, что выполняет деструктор класса. Для класса:

```
class A1 {
    static int i;
public:
    ~A1() { cout << "call: " << ++i << endl ; }
    void remove() { this->~A1(); }
};
int A1::i = 0;
```

вызоа деструктора совершенно безопасен  (вызывайте сколько угодно раз), так как деструктор ничего не делает, кроме тривиального вывода количества вызовов.  Он не освобождает память, а вызывается перед уничтожением обьекта.

Для классов, где в деструкторе осуществляются операции освобождения памяти, например такого как:

```
class A2 {
    int*  pi;
public:
    A2() : pi(new int(1)) {}
    ~A2() {   delete pi;}
    //...
    void remove() { this->~A2(); }
};
```

`remove` уже проблема (смотреть комментарии от `Harry`  и  `VTT`)